# Check if JAVA_HOME is present in environment using batch script

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I want to check whether JAVA_HOME is present in environment or not
So I wrote the below script `a.bat`

```
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" 
(
echo Enter path to JAVA_HOME: 
set /p javahome=
)
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == ""
(
echo %JAVA_HOME%
)
```

It shows "The syntax of the command is incorrect" where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
IF "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    echo Enter path to JAVA_HOME: 
    set /p JAVA_HOME=
) ELSE (
    echo %JAVA_HOME%
)
```

Comment: Doesn't fly for windows 10

Answer (score 2):

```
if not defined JAVA_HOME (
    :undefined
    set /p JAVA_HOME=Enter path to JAVA_HOME:
    if not defined JAVA_HOME goto:undefined
 )
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Comment: This requires command extensions so you might want to explicitly set those first even though they are on by default. SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Unable to enable extensions