# Can't start the Elastic service in Windows 10

Tags: java, elasticsearch, windows-10

Similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25580385/1525840) but with a different OS. I've installed the latest Java and verified by:

> > java -version
>
> java version "1.8.0_191"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

I also make sure that *JAVA_HOME* is set as system variable and verify it by:

> > $env:java_home
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_192

Then, I tried both ZIP installation and MSI installation of the Elastic Windows Service. It's installed but doesn't run. When forced manually, it says that it can't do that on the local system (1067, the process terminated unexpectedly).

I tried to reinstall all the relevant components. I tried *scm /scannow* and reimporting the keys into registry. I tried to re-set the user and system environment variables. Etc. I'm out of ideas.

I noticed that there's no *logs* directory in *Elastic* installation root. Also, there's no configuration files in that directory as far I could see. Where exactly should they be located so I can check what's logged and play around with different settings.

Comment: By default, Elasticsearch will be installed at `%PROGRAMFILES%\Elastic\Elasticsearch` unless you chose a custom location during installation. Logs directory will be created and written to during Elasticsearch service start up. It appears that service is failing even before then. Ideally there should be a config file under `%PROGRAMFILES%\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config` directory. Did Elasticsearch install successfully ?

Comment: @ben5556 Thanks for the info, mate. It seems as the installation goes wrong as there's no config directory in said location. The other stuff are there (*bin*, *lib*, *modules*, *plugins* and some text files). That's it. How did you install Elastic - ZIP or MSI style? And what version do you have experience with? I took the newest one, of course.

Comment: I installed it using msi on Win 7 without any issues and also several times on Linux.

Comment: @ben5556 Interesting... I'm doing Win 10 but I hardly believe that's the problem. I got it working on my Buntu, though, so I suspect that there's something specific to my system. Might be some corporate thingy policy crap.